# How do I run terminal in sudo mode?

Tags: terminal, sudo, root

I was trying to install [npm](http://npmjs.org/), and I got

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, Permission denied '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please use 'sudo' or log in as root to run this command.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     sudo npm "install" "." "--force" "--global"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! or set the 'unsafe-perm' config var to true.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

How can log in as a root?

Comment: Do not login as root. ;-)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`sudo -s` is far easier than [enabling the root user](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528) since it just starts up a shell with root permissions as a one step, on demand action. Not only is it fast, but it doesn't need to be reconfigured when you don't need the root user and doesn't expose the server to any more risk or vulnerability that adding a root user would entail.

Of course for `npm` you could just follow the directions and type:

```
sudo -H npm "install" "." "--force" "--global"
```

That still makes the `npm` command "root" and skips the log out step to get back out of root.

Comment: But better to sudo the one command rather than run under a shell as root

Comment: Could you explain what `sudo -s` does in this context?

Comment: @KatieK The command `sudo -s` runs a shell as root. The [manual page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) has these details and much more. I will add some words since your question is a good one and many others might also wonder what it does.

Answer (score 13):

I usually do it bit differently than how others described here.
Lets imagine you have two users.
standard user: john
admin user: kevin

If john is logged in and wants to run as a root user(as kevin) here is how I do it.

```
su kevin
```

when asked enter kevin's password

```
sudo npm "install" "." "--force" "--global"
```

enter kevin's password again.

Comment: After you've already switched user to kevin, why do you need the `sudo`?

Comment: Because Kevin is not root, he is just allowed to become root.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `su` (switch user) command to become root, but only root is allowed to become root, so you need to use `sudo` (super-user do). Therefore, type: `sudo su`.

```
[william@NCC-1701 ~]$ sudo su
Password:
[root@NCC-1701 /Users/william]$
```

If you haven't used root before, you should be made fully aware that one wrong character typed as root will delete your entire operating system, including your photos, emails and financial documents. Be extremely careful and always triple-read what you type before hitting enter. Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: been an AIX support technician for 3 years ... 12 years ago :) know some stuff but the simple stuff had vanished from my head :)

Comment: I was going to snark my answer with friendly manual and google suggestions but quickly deleted it after reading your bio. Welcome to mac. I still can't bring myself to type vm_stat after years of AIX. Gotta love shell aliases ;-)

Comment: Why use `sudo su` instead of `sudo -s`?

Comment: All I see is NCC-1701 lol

Comment: @ShaneHsu  good one!! i loved your comment...

Answer (score 2):

I ran the same issue trying to install ionic, you only need to run the same command with `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
```

The system will request the current user’s password. Provide it, and you will be able to install as superuser.

Answer (score 2):

Other than what people have said you can run `sudo <your-shell>` this brings up the shell with root priveleges

```
sudo zsh
```

Comment: How does this differ from running `sudo -s` as explained in the accepted answer?

Comment: @nohillside this might be too specific, but oh my zsh autocomplete doesn't autocomplete files in `sudo -s zsh` but works in `sudo zsh`