# A mysterious "Other…" user has appeared on my login screen

Tags: macos, login-screen

I know this is often caused by enabling the root user, but checking the Directory Utility app — as instructed in other threads on this topic — has shown me that this user isn't at all enabled.

Only software I can think of that can be responsible for this is NoMachine which I use for remote access. But I just want to rule out malware at this point and figure how the hell can I get rid of this "user" (when I click on the its avatar I'm prompted to enter both a username and a password)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have recently installed an app that utilizes a new user account.
NoMachine is one example. if you delete it, `other...` icon will be gone.

Comment: Is there a way to remove Other... without removing NoMachine (I have not confirmed this is the cause in my case, though I do have NoMachine recently installed).

Comment: See my posted answer I just found. It may help someone.

Comment: What would be the consequences or implications of simply "deleting" this user, even if benign?

Answer (score 0):

Once you review your accounts, the mystery will be revealed. Apple designed that item to let you enter a user name and password for system or other accounts from a directory server. It also can indicate if you allow guests to connect to your Mac in a secure manner.

[image]
Above is the guest access configuration on Catalina. In the past a lot of people enabled the root account, but more new macOS don’t need that and have protected system so any Admin user is really root or [can become root in a shell on demand using the `sudo` command.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/how-do-i-run-terminal-in-sudo-mode)

Comment: How can I know which app caused the creation of this account?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer in the Apple Community...

Open Terminal and enter:
`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool FALSE`

This may work for some (I have not tested it).

Source: ["Other" User Account Suddenly Appears](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251249886?answerId=252398379022#252398379022)

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this is to Disable Root User. To do that, go to:

> System Preferences > Users & Groups > Unlock Button (and put in
>   password) > Login Options > Network Account Server: click "Join" >
>   Open Directory Utility > Unlock Button (and put in password) > Edit
>   Menu (at the top) > **DISABLE ROOT USER**

Once you've done that, the Other... user should be gone from the login screen.

Alternatively, you can get to Directory Utility using Spotlight (command + spacebar) then typing Directory Utility, and pressing enter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the Edit menu shows my root user isn't enabled. (The option is: "Enable Root User")

Comment: Likewise! This did not work for the same reason.

Comment: So I have read that this may also be one of the reasons. So it depends on one's system. I'm unclear how this would happen though.   Also, it would be nice to know what the consequences or implications of either solution might be, even if benign.