# Can't install Bower

Tags: permission, package-management

I am logged in with my local acccount, I even sudoed to that account with SSH.

I tried to install Bower with the following command:

```
npm install -g bower
```

and I get this error:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib
└── bower@1.7.9 

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
```

The error is pretty obvious, I have 2 questions:

1. Why does it happen with my local super admin account?
2. How can I fix this?

Comment: From what you wrote it seems you are running the command with a regular user account without the permission to write in the mentioned directory. The phrase "*sudoed to that account with SSH*" is incomprehensible.

Comment: How did you "sudoed to that account with SSH"

Comment: Please read this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/14423/22003 .

Answer (score 2):

Check your effective permission:

```
id
```

will tell you if you have the required priviledge (`uid=0(root) ...`).

Then be carefull upon using `sudo`. Be warned it is pretty easy to trap admin beginners into using a wrong `sudo` so as to steal their password.
Always use the standard and explicit path of `sudo`:

```
/usr/bin/sudo npm ...
```

or if you prefer check that you aren't using the wrong one:

```
type sudo
```

which should reply with the correct answer:

```
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo
```

(and nothing else which would be a bad sign).

Answer (score 1):

Try this command instead:

> **sudo** npm install -g bower