# How to run a root/admin shell in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, administrator

How can I run a shell as Admin in Terminal if Im logged in as User with standard privileges? I know the passwords for user and admin account

Comment: Open a terminal window, execute the command `su` and carry on.  So straightforward I'm sure I'm missing the point ...

Comment: btw, admin != root

Comment: Okay, then I need to run terminal as username: Admin while i'm logged in username:user

Comment: What exactly do you want to do that `sudo` is not sufficient?  There seems to be a lot missing from this question.

Comment: What do you want to do once you have a Terminal running as root/admin? Or do you basically just need a `bash`/shell running with root/admin permissions?

Comment: @patrix yes I need shell running with root/admin permissions

Comment: There is no such thing as root/admin what do you want to actually do?

Comment: Let’s close this as dupe. Unless the OP can clearly break out what they’re going to do once they’re root - this is totally the same as the linked question - use an admin shell to `sudo -s` and you are root on any and all macOS systems out of the box, no fiddling with enabling root user or setting a root password.

Answer (score 6):

One easy way is to su to the admin user than use `sudo -s` to become root shell.

```
su - shortname_for_admin
sudo -s
```

This also is covered well in the linked questions:

- [Run sudo From Non-Admin Account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126397/run-sudo-from-non-admin-account)
- [How do I run terminal in sudo mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/how-do-i-run-terminal-in-sudo-mode)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has to do with the `/etc/sudoers` file, which is shown at the end of this answer. The important line is repeated below.

```
%admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

This line gives the administrator accounts the ability to use the `sudo` command. If you know the user name and password for an administrator account, the enter the commands given below to become the root user. When prompted for a `login:`, enter the user name for the administrator account. When prompted for a `Password:`, enter the password for the administrator account.

```
login
sudo  login  -f  root
```

To return to your user account, enter the commands given below.

```
exit
exit
```

### Appendix

Output from `cat  /etc/sudoers`.

```
#
# Sample /etc/sudoers file.
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.

##
# Override built-in defaults
##
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep += "BLOCKSIZE"
Defaults    env_keep += "COLORFGBG COLORTERM"
Defaults    env_keep += "__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING"
Defaults    env_keep += "CHARSET LANG LANGUAGE LC_ALL LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME"
Defaults    env_keep += "LINES COLUMNS"
Defaults    env_keep += "LSCOLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
Defaults    env_keep += "TZ"
Defaults    env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
Defaults    env_keep += "HOME MAIL"

Defaults    lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture"

##
# User alias specification
##
# User_Alias    FULLTIMERS = millert, mikef, dowdy

##
# Runas alias specification
##
# Runas_Alias   OP = root, operator

##
# Host alias specification
##
# Host_Alias    CUNETS = 128.138.0.0/255.255.0.0
# Host_Alias    CSNETS = 128.138.243.0, 128.138.204.0/24, 128.138.242.0
# Host_Alias    SERVERS = master, mail, www, ns
# Host_Alias    CDROM = orion, perseus, hercules

##
# Cmnd alias specification
##
# Cmnd_Alias    PAGERS = /usr/bin/more, /usr/bin/pg, /usr/bin/less

##
# User specification
##

# root and users in group wheel can run anything on any machine as any user
root        ALL = (ALL) ALL
%admin      ALL = (ALL) ALL

## Read drop-in files from /private/etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d
```